# A word similar to listening or attentive

Tags: american-english, synonyms, listening

We are looking for a word that is similar to listening or attentive.   For a use in describing the nature of our corporation's relationship with our employees and customers.

Comment: I think you could improve this question by talking more about the situation and explaining why the words "listening" or "attentive" do not work. For that matter, what happened when you consulted a thesaurus? What was wrong with the options you saw there?

Comment: If you're in the US you might want to avoid committing yourself to using the same word for both your employees and your customers, especially if you're doing business in a state with "right-to-work" laws on the books.

Answer (score 1):

**Attentive** seems perfectly viable (as in "Attentive to the needs of our..."). Another word you could use is **Responsive**, which implies an ability to adapt or change when customers change their minds or needs.

Answer (score 0):

It's almost a cliché but you could say that your company [cares](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/care) [MWD] about its employees and/or customers

> regard coming from desire or esteem

[Sensitive](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sensitive) [MWD]

> aware of and understanding the feelings of other people

or [responsive](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/responsive) [MWD]

> reacting in a desired or positive way

might also work for you